# Calculate DC-Gain from step response at high frequency

Tags: control-system

[image]

How can I calculate the DC-Gain at high frequencies from the above step response? Also, how is it different from the DC-Gain at low frequencies that is equal to 2?

Comment: "DC" is the lowest possible frequency, so it's not clear what you mean by "DC-gain at high frequencies".

Comment: he probably mean scalar gain, ie P-term

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit is linear then DC gain is the gain at 0Hz. Nothing to add, nothing to remove. In your example the DC gain is 2. Nothing to add, nothing to remove - assuming your circuit is linear.

In a nonlinear circuit we have free hands te define the concept of the DC gain. We could declare for example how and from what frequency range we take the possible rectifying results into the account.

You have not given any declaration nor nonlinearity description. Thus the DC gain is 2 regardless of other frequencies. Nothing to add, nothing to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Underdamped response time can be 1st order or higher and bandwidth is often rated according to rise time with some assumptions on the slope of the bandwidth.

The simplest method is use f-3dB = 0.35/Tr for Tr from 10 to 90%  ( half power).  Since this starts at 1V , I assume this is 0% and estimate Tr from 1.1 to 1.9V = (3.4s-0.2s)=3.2s

Thus f-3dB = 0.35/3.2s ~ 0.11 Hz

Notice if a triangle wave were applied its peak to peak amplitude would be reduced more than half.

Neglect if you don't understand yet, but I inserted the log harmonics for a square wave ( not a step ) so you can see the frequency response can also be measure in dB per odd harmonics on this square wave .  (Fourier Spectrum)

Normally the 0.707 Vpp is the f-3dB point which squared becomes half power related so the expected AC gain at -3dB is 0.707 x Av(=2) = 1.4 approx. at 0.11 Hz. and Av=2 at DC (given)

[image]

I cannot be more precise than this "estimate" without more details,  that are not critical for now. e.g. if 1st order , then use asymptote from start of step output and use \$RC=T = 1/(2\pi f_{-3dB})~~~\$ = 1.5s